# My indoor lemon tree is an offshoot. What should I do?

Tags: indoors, citrus, lemons

I ordered a couple Meyer lemon trees online, and I'm hoping I can pull them off indoors with less than ideal light. One of the trees is offset with the main branch sealed. It's not the best look for a tree growing on my windowsill. I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to train it to grow up straight and healthy. Should I give it a crutch or will that hurt the little guy?

[image: Bent Meyer Lemon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, loosely tie it to a chopstick or other support in two or three places and it will grow upright.  With good light you might get some buds off the trunk.  If that doesn't happen and it remains spindly you should move it to better light so it will assume the more natural bushy shape.

Comment: Thanks. I braced it a couple weeks ago. It's still alive, but scrawny. We'll see how it goes.